# HTML CSS - Without folder works with doesn't

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, href

EDIT: I don't what I did that is different from what i wrote below but it works now. don't know why :-/ thank you guys for the help :)

I am trying to link my document to a css file. the problem is that.

This works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

This dosent:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

And of course the file exist in the sub folder when i try to link to it.

:)

EDIT:

HTML file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<table id="menu">
<tr>
<td><a id="button">Home</a></td>
<td><a id="button">Education</a></td>
<td><a id="button">Experience</a></td>
<td><a id="button">Gallery</a></td>
<td><a id="button">Cantact Me</a></td></tr>

</table>
```

it seems it worked only in my html editor (Expression Web) but when i open it in a browser (chrome/firefox/ie) it doesnt work.

Style File:

```
 body{ background-color: white;} 

 #menu { width:100%; background-image:url('BarBG.png'); border:0px;  }
 #button 
 { 
 color:white; 
 font-size:large; 
 line-height:45px; 
 vertical-align:middle; 
 text-align:center;
 display: block; 
 width: 100px; 
 height: 45px;
 margin-right:auto; 
 margin-left:auto;
   }
   #button:hover{


color:black; 
font-size:large; 
line-height:45px; 
vertical-align:middle; 
text-align:center;
display: block; 
width: 100px; 
height: 45px;
margin-right:auto; 
margin-left:auto;
background-image:url('BarBGHover2.png');
cursor:pointer;  
}
```

Comment: And what's the directory structure of your site? Where is the HTML file? We can make guesses, but this question can't be realistically answered without more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trey making the link relative to the root

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
```

Comment: it worked, but for some reason now the text in my tables is aligned to the left instead of middle/center

Comment: @Xirox are both the CSS files identical? Like bobek asked, how do you know it worked? Does your HTML have inline css that would override the alignment code? Please post a snippet of the code in question and we can help further.

Comment: well, because i can see the images and styles unlike it was before where i couldn't see any style applied. just wondering about the alignment :-/

Comment: Alignment is your CSS error not related to the question. I'd create a new question with a new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
```

The `./` implies relative from where it is being called from. Not always needed but can sometimes help. :)